# read in *.tar.gz-file with internal directory structure

Tags: r, gzip

I want to read a *.tar.gz-file. In that file there are several files in a directory-structure. If I untar it manually in my current directory will be created the structure:

opt/path/to/the/file.csv

opt/path/to/another_file.txt

Is there a way in R to extract or reed just file.csv?

I´ve already tried to untar the file:

```
untar(tarfile = "file.tar.gz"
  , exdir = "./working/"
  )
# and then I could read it as usual with read.table()
```

But in ./working there do not occur the expected directory opt/path/to/the/

**Edit:**

verbose = T: do not result any output.

If I untar an *.tar.gz-file with just the file.csv in it, in directory ./working occure that file.csv. The `verbose = TRUE` does not result an output, too.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. Your command works perfectly for me. Could you perhaps use the verbose switch of `untar()` and see if this turns up some more information? (`untar(tarfile="file.tar.gz", exdir="./working", verbose=TRUE)`)

Comment: In my case, untar with verbose results in a confirmation of the command, like this: `untar: using cmd = '/usr/bin/tar -zxf 'file.tar.gz' -C './working/''` What version of R are you using? what version of untar? on what OS?